# Calculating the n needed to discern a certain proportion effect in a linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, statistical-power

As title says, I was wondering how one would go about calculating the n needed to discern a certain proportion effect in a linear regression and additionally calculating the discernable effect given the n. The example as follows, assume dependent variable y and independent continuous variables a and b, for `y ~ a`, how would I calculate the n needed to discern a say 5% change as statistically significant, or how would I for a given n know what change this is "powered" for.

Comment: Do you know the baseline rate?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov what do you mean by this?

Comment: The answer depends on if you’re going from .05 to .1 or from .5 to .55. The first number is the baseline rate.

Comment: I know the values for y and a. The coefficient which would represent a unit change is the one at question. Is there another way of looking at this?

Comment: The baseline is the intercept.

Comment: Oh, yes, then, I have the intercept.

Comment: And what might it be?

Comment: 18.928169  with std error 15.307907

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have
$$y_i=a + b \cdot x_i + \varepsilon_i \text{ for i=1,}\dots
\text{,n, }\varepsilon_i \overset{iid}{\sim} N[0,\sigma^2]$$

I am assuming you want to test the null $H_0:b=0$ against the two-sided alternative that $H_a: b \ne 0$.

Here I will use Stata to calculate the required sample size $n$ to detect a 5% increase from the baseline of 18.928169 for a one unit increase in $x$:

```
. power oneslope 0 `=18.928169*.05', sdx(.5) alpha(.05) sdy(1 5 10 20)

Performing iteration ...

Estimated sample size for a linear regression slope test
t test
H0: b = b0  versus  Ha: b != b0

  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |   alpha   power       N   delta      b0      ba     sdx sderror     sdy |
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |     .05      .8      30   .5372       0   .9464      .5    .881       1 |
  |     .05      .8     871  .09507       0   .9464      .5   4.978       5 |
  |     .05      .8   3,500  .04737       0   .9464      .5   9.989      10 |
  |     .05      .8   14015  .02367       0   .9464      .5   19.99      20 |
  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here I made an assumption about the standard deviation of $x$ and varied the assumption about the standard deviation of $y$. You can get those from your own data quite easily.

Alternatively, you can compute power given sample size and the slope coefficient, or else compute the target slope coefficient given sample size, power, and the coefficient under the null.

Unfortunately, there is no simple formula, and the sample size comes from iteratively solving a nonlinear equation. There are formulas in the Methods and Formulas section [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals/pss-2poweroneslope.pdf). In practice, most people would use some software or an online calculator to carry this out.

Comment: @Cenoc Did this clear things up?